# Changing WinEdt's local folder

Tags: winedt

I have a cloud and use WinEdt on several computers (laptop, office pc, etc.). I would like to have a local WinEdt folder in my cloud, so that all my devices share the same information like, e.g., the user dictionary and macros, etc. Is it possible to change the local WinEdt folder in this way?

By the way, I use WinEdt 8 (v. 8.1) [Build: 20131031].

Comment: Have you tried this? → `Options` -> `Configuration Wizard`, in the `wizard` tab change the path to `%b` in the last field (just above `OK` button) to your cloud address. Worth giving a try.

Comment: Yes, check the manual pages about "Command Line Switches" and "Configuration Wizard". But imho it is not a good idea to share everything. There are always slight difference between computers. E.g. the path to the pdf reader and to the tex-system, "recent file" lists, backups etc. So you should be careful.

Comment: Dear Harish, yes, I tried this. Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the local folder in the configuration wizard. This holds even if I am logged in as administrator.

Comment: Dear Ulrike, you are right. I am aware of that problem. It's just about the user dictionary and my own active strings. I am not much interested in sharing local paths, etc.

Comment: Well dictionaries should be easy. You only need to adapt the pathes in the dictionaries.ini. For active strings: imho you could `%INCLUDE` your definitions. I personally have a config.edt that I load at startup on every PC which defines variable for the specific pathes of this PC that I can use in winedt macros and ini-files. E.g. `Assign("UFTeXLivePath14","D:\texlive\2014\bin\win32;");`

Comment: I guess that's a pretty solution to my problem! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is solved. I made the following simple modifications:
1. I changed the path to my user dictionary in Dictionaries.ini to C:\Cloud\Local\WinEdt\User.dic.
2. I changed the path to my own active strings, accordingly.

Presumably, it is not a good idea to remove the local folder of a specific system to the cloud, since each system has its own local settings. By contrast, the given solution is stable, robust, and sufficient.